# JAVA equivalent of verifying login info?

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, authentication, jframe

I've never used databases with JAVA before so please bear with me. I'm stuck with the MySQL queries.
I'm creating a GUI whereby the user has to enter his email address as well as his password before getting access to the Main page. When the user clicks on the Submit button a database connection is set and there's a MySQL query which selects fields corresponding to the data entered.
With PHP, i would normally use the $_POST to get the data entered but for JAVA GUI, i've understood that i need to save the data entered in a string, which i did.
Now, after the select statement, i'm supposed to display the other window if the email address and password is correct.
That's where i'm stuck. The other window is not displaying and i don't know how to verify the data entered for login.

Please find my codes below:

LoginForm.java:

```
package interfaceGUI;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class LoginForm extends JFrame{

private JLabel loginEmail;
private JLabel loginPass;
private JTextField loginTextField;
private JPasswordField loginPassField;
private JButton submit;
private JPanel loginArea;
private JPanel buttonArea;

public LoginForm()
{
    super("Party Supplies Rental");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    loginEmail = new JLabel("Enter Your Email Address: ");
    loginTextField = new JTextField(20);
    loginPass = new JLabel("Enter Your Password: ");
    loginPassField = new JPasswordField(20);

    loginArea = new JPanel();
    loginArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

    loginArea.add(loginEmail); //add to the JPanel
    loginArea.add(loginTextField);
    loginArea.add(loginPass);
    loginArea.add(loginPassField);
    add(loginArea); //add JPanel to the frame

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    buttonArea = new JPanel();
    buttonArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    buttonArea.add(submit);
    add(buttonArea);

    ButtonHandler handler= new ButtonHandler();

    submit.addActionListener(handler);
}

public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource() == submit)
        {

            String loginText = loginTextField.getText();
            char[] passText = loginPassField.getPassword();

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
            String dbName = "partySupplies";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String username = "root";
            String pw = "";

            try
            {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,username,pw);
                //System.out.println("Connected");

                Statement s = conn.createStatement();


                //s.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES('2', 'Krishna', 'Rohee', 'Grand Bois', '56546546', 'krishnarohee@gmail.com', 'daminimobbdou')");

                s.execute("SELECT custEmailAdd, custPassword FROM login WHERE custEmailAdd = 'loginText' AND custPassword = 'passText'");
                ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
                int rowCount = rs.getRow();

                //while loop here to check for login data
                {
                dispose();
                Main main = new Main();
                main.setSize(500,200);
                main.setVisible(true);
                conn.close();
                }
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

    }
}

}
```

The Main.java:

```
package interfaceGUI;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame{

private JLabel label;
private JPanel forLabel;
private JButton birthdayCategory;
private JButton summerCategory;
private JButton halloweenCategory;
private JPanel forCategory;


public Main()
{
    super("Home");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label = new JLabel("Choose the Party Category");
    forLabel = new JPanel();
    forLabel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    forLabel.add(label);
    add(forLabel);

    birthdayCategory = new JButton("Birthday Party");
    summerCategory = new JButton("Summer/Festive Party");
    halloweenCategory = new JButton("Halloween Party");
    forCategory = new JPanel();
    forCategory.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    forCategory.add(birthdayCategory);
    forCategory.add(summerCategory);
    forCategory.add(halloweenCategory);
    add(forCategory);
}

}
```

In simple words, when the user clicks on the submit button, i want to verify the data entered by the user and then display the Main.java window.
Please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `loginText` and `passText` to the SQL query, so your database receives this query exactly as you wrote it:

```
"SELECT custEmailAdd, custPassword FROM login WHERE custEmailAdd = 'loginText' AND custPassword = 'passText'"
```

In order to pass your variables' values, you need to insert them to this SQL statement, like this:

```
s.execute( String.format( "SELECT custEmailAdd, custPassword FROM login WHERE custEmailAdd = '%s' AND custPassword = '%s'", loginText, new String( passText ) ) );
```

But for better performance I'd advice you to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT custEmailAdd, custPassword FROM login WHERE custEmailAdd = ? AND custPassword = ?");
ps.setString( 1, loginText );
ps.setString( 2, new String( passText ) );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

As for checking the result set, you may just verify if at least one result is returned: if yes, then user with such credentials exist, if no - there's no user with such credentials.

```
if( rs.next() )
{
  dispose();
  Main main = new Main();
  main.setSize(500,200);
  main.setVisible(true);
  conn.close();
}
else
{
  // show some error
}
```

By the way, it's **very bad** practice to initialize database connection in the action listener. You should better do the initialization in a static block or in constructor, because it is a time-consuming operation. Also you would benefit if сarry out `PreparedStatement` constructor, too. Then you just set the parameters and execute request where you need.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. After a while i figured out i was passing the wrong values. You made it simpler by checking only for the number of rows. I will use the PreparedStatement instead.